# When I call a query from Access using VBA, I can't know how many records are on that query. Why?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I did a query on MS Access 2010, with the Query Builder, now I'm calling it from VBA. But when I try to use the recordcount to know how many records are on this query, the result is -1.

The code:

```vb
Public Function teste(Optional ByVal consulta As String, Optional ByVal cbAR_valor As String, Optional ByVal cbAR_valor2 As String)

Dim DB As ADODB.Connection
Dim RST As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Query As ADODB.Command
Dim parametro1 As ADODB.Parameter
Dim parametro2 As ADODB.Parameter

On Error GoTo trataErro

DB_Dir = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "DB2.accdb"

Set DB = New ADODB.Connection
DB.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DB_Dir & ";Persist Security Info=False"

Set Query = New ADODB.Command
Set Query.ActiveConnection = DB
Query.CommandText = consulta
Query.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

' Pego o valor do param. e adiciono no command
Set parametro1 = Query.CreateParameter("AR1", adChar, adParamInput, 255)
Query.Parameters.Append parametro1
parametro1.Value = cbAR_valor

' Pego o valor do param. e adiciono no command
Set parametro2 = Query.CreateParameter("AR2", adChar, adParamInput, 255)
Query.Parameters.Append parametro2
parametro2.Value = cbAR_valor2


Set RST = Query.Execute

a = RST.RecordCount

linha = 1
coluna = 1
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Plan2").Cells(CInt(linha), CInt(coluna)).CopyFromRecordset RST

DB.Close
Set DB = Nothing

Exit Function

trataErro:
    MsgBox ("Erro: " & Err.Description)


End Function
```

Comment: Does this code work? The line with `DB_Dir = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "DB2.accdb"` is missing a backslash: "\\" (the [escape sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) for a backslash).

Comment: [Commandtext](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_comm_commandtext.asp) should be in quotes.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/194973

Comment: When the DB doesn't support the recordcount ability, unless the query is large and complex, try executing a sql just before that counts the records, and use that as the total number of returned records. To be safe, always check if EOF also.

Answer (score 2):

`RecordCount` is tricky.  Depending on the provider, data source type, and options, it may not be reliable.

For an ADO recordset, you are more likely to get a reliable `RecordCount` with a client-side cursor:

```vb
Set DB = New ADODB.Connection
DB.CursorLocation = adUseClient '<- add this
DB.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DB_Dir & ";Persist Security Info=False"
```

I assumed your procedure's *consulta* argument is a SQL statement.  If that is correct, use *adCmdText* (instead of *adCmdStoredProc*) for `CommandType`:

```vb
Set Query = New ADODB.Command
'Set Query.ActiveConnection = DB ' Set not needed here ...
Query.ActiveConnection = DB
Query.CommandText = consulta
'Query.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
Query.CommandType = adCmdText
```

If those changes were not sufficient to get you a reliable `RecordCount`, use `MoveLast` to ensure the recordset is fully populated before asking for `RecordCount`:

```vb
Set RST = Query.Execute
RST.MoveLast
MsgBox "RecordCount: " & RST.RecordCount
```

Add `RST.MoveFirst` afterward if you need the recordset pointer to be on the first row in preparation for your remaining operations.

Answer (score 0):

When I've had trouble with counting records before, the issue was with the way the recordset was opened, not the connection.  The [cursor type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681771(v=vs.85).aspx) needs to be static for it to work.  This may be very similar to what HansUp was referring to with the cursorlocation in the connection object, though.

```
rec.Open querystr, con, 3
rec.movelast
cnt = rec.RecordCount
rec.movefirst
```

Comment: How do you set cursor type to static with an `ADODB.Command`?  Not saying it can't be done, just that I don't see how to do it.

Comment: Good question, I don't know either.  I've always just opened a recordset using the `open` method.  Is there any disadvantage to this?

Comment: pedrocsa is using a parameter query.  Seems to me that `ADODB.Command` is way to go.  If you want to do it via only an `ADODB.Recordset`, you'd have to supply the parameters somehow or rewrite the SQL statement.